# Load script after tempateURL

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Hi guys i need to understand what can i do for load a script after that ngRoute load the templateURL.
I need to instance two slider after that page load templateUrl file html.

i use angularJs and ngRoute. i think controller is execute before HTML finish to load template file.

i have this code:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider){
//set route
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'page/configurator.html',
        controller: 'mainController'        
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo:'/'
    })
}); 
app.controller('mainController', function($scope){
    //data for main=configurator controller    
    //$scope.message="Everyone come and see how good I look! i am in MAIN=configurator page";
    $scope.pageTitle="SELECT THE ICE TYPES AND MAX DAILY PRODUCTS";    
    alert("test");
    $(window).trigger("resize");    
});
```

what can i do for run script after html is insert in my page?

thanks
VR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The post-link function is the last phase of a directive's render cycle and it also gets called from inner-most element to outer-most. So you can use this on a top level element to detect when angular has rendered all child directives (ng and otherwise).

```
app.directive('onFinishRender', function ($timeout,$rootScope) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            $timeout(function () {
                $rootScope.$broadcast("hasFinishedRender");
            });
        }
    }
})


app.controller('mainController', function($scope){
    $scope.$on('hasFinishedRender',function(){
        // load script dynamically using any method
        var my_awesome_script = document.createElement('script');
        my_awesome_script.setAttribute('src','http://example.com/site.js');
        document.head.appendChild(my_awesome_script);
    });
});
```

You'll probably also want some logic to keep it from firing multiple times on future digest cycles. Also assuming angular 1.x

Comment: thanks for yor reply, i try to put this directive  <div onFinishRender></div>  in body as first element (my app ng-app is on html tag) but nothing.
i think that directive call onFinishRender that fire event hasFinishedRender with .$brodcast method, it's correct?

Comment: if i insert an alert on main controller it's show two times, why?
in my case script it's loaded two times, at first loop generate an error and in second loop it's ok, but i have two slider...what can i do?

Comment: CORRECT, i call controller in router and in page, now i call controller only in html page

Comment: You need to put in logic to keep it from firing twice like I said